# Exporting metadata from PostGIS tables to shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, export, metadata

With QGIS, the description of a dataset seems to be available for filling and consultation via the 'information' and 'metadata' tabs in "LAYER PROPERTIES". There seem to be bridges between PostGIS and QGIS. For example, when I fill the "Comment" field of a table with pgadmin, the content of the description is visible with QGIS in the "Information" menu in the Comment line and in the Abstract line. The description is also visible in the "Metadata" menu in the Summary section / Identification tab.

For some PostGIS tables, I have also described the data using the useful Pgmetadata plugin.

My need would be to be able to export these different data descriptions during exports from these PostGIS tables toward files in shp format for example. That these descriptions be kept during the export.

If it is possible, then which tools / resources exist to do this?